# How do I completely remove Exceptionless from a server?

Tags: exceptionless

I recently installed Exceptionless on a server for testing purposes.  Now how do I go about completely removing it from said server?  I have uninstalled and deleted all the directories for both ElasticSearch and Exceptionless.  When I reinstall it again, it says my email already exists.  I basically need to completely remove the tool from my system, so that I can try different configurations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on the Exceptionless Project. You just need to remove the website and Elasticsearch instance that you configured (if you only set it up for Exceptionless). If you delete the Elasticsearch folder you should be completely free. If you are using redis, you may want to flush the redis db to start over. Were you able to get it working?